# Get mouse screen coordinates on click

Tags: c++, winapi, firebreath

How can I get mouse screen coordinates right after user clicks left mouse button (mose click coordinates - in another words). It's for a plugin written with FireBreath.
I was tryin to use:

```
FB::variant TestPluginAPI::Detect()
{
POINT pt;

if (WM_LBUTTONUP)
{
    GetCursorPos(&pt);
}
FB::VariantList Dtd = FB::variant_list_of(pt.x)(pt.y);
return Dtd;
```

it's returning JavaScript Array `Dtd` with `pt.x` and `pt.y` in it, then I'm using this array to render this coordinates on my page via JS.
This one gives me mouse coords only on page start.

Then I was trying `WM_LBUTTONUP == MK_RBUTTON` in `if`; It gives me some random huge numbers... what can I do?
Will you kindly help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get mouse position in your javascript function, you can make a callback JSAPI function in your plugin and invoke it when left mouse button is clicked with arguments as FB::VariantList of mouse co-ordinates. You can detect mouse click by overloading the onMouseDown event in the class which inherits from FB::PluginCore. To register onMouseDown event, you can use following code in the header.

 `BEGIN_PLUGIN_EVENT_MAP() 

          EVENTTYPE_CASE(FB::MouseDownEvent, onMouseDown, FB::PluginWindow)
 END_PLUGIN_EVENT_MAP()`

virtual bool onMouseDown(FB::MouseDownEvent *evt, FB::PluginWindow *);

onMouseDown can be defined as - 

`bool MirrarOrnaments::onMouseDown(FB::MouseDownEvent *evt, FB::PluginWindow *) 

{`

if(evt->m_Btn == FB::MouseButtonEvent::MouseButton_Left) 
      {
          /** 
             * apiPtr is the pointer to FB::JSAPIPtr   
             * mousePositionCallback is the JSAPI function which takes variant list of mouse 
            * co-ordinates as argument 
             */ 
            apiPtr->invoke("mousePositionCallback", FB::variant_list_of(evt->m_x)(evt->m_y)); 
      }
}

Hope this is what you are trying to ask. Your question is kind of vague.

Comment: Can you give me some tip, how this apiPtr can possibly look in my code, i just don't understand how can I correctly write it, and how can I get it

Comment: Your apiPtr is FB::JSAPIPtr which you return in createJSAPI function. You can assign it like this - apiPtr = PluginAPIPtr(new PluginAPI(FB::ptr_cast<Plugin>(shared_from_this()), m_host));

Answer (score 1):

WM_LBUTTONUP is a WinAPi function, so you should have access to lParam which goes along with the message.

```
xPos = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam); 
yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
```

Comment: lParam? What do you mean by "have access"? Is it part of window function? But if it's plugin for browser can i get "access" to it?

Comment: You tagged the question with winapi and used WM_LBUTTONUP so I assumed that you get the windows message event, which includes an lParam. Where did you get this WM_LBUTTONUP from? The lParam is an additional information and in case of the button up event it sends the current X/Y position at the time of the event.

Comment: Can i jsut get mouse coords on click regardless of windows message event of my window? Cos i a bit confused right now, can i get it for browser window.

Comment: GetCursorPos will give you the screen coordinates of the mouse. If you need them realtive to your window you may have to calculate the position from that. What do you mean ba "random numbers"? Can you give an example?