# Firebreath C++ some pointer understanding

Tags: c++, winapi, pointers, firebreath

I asked one question here [Get mouse screen coordinates on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509130/get-mouse-screen-coordinates-on-click) and got a good answer (confirmed one), thx `Gaurav Raj` for this.
And in this sample:

```
bool MirrarOrnaments::onMouseDown(FB::MouseDownEvent *evt, FB::PluginWindow *) 
{
  if(evt->m_Btn == FB::MouseButtonEvent::MouseButton_Left) 
  {
    /** 
     * apiPtr is the pointer to FB::JSAPIPtr 
     * mousePositionCallback is the JSAPI function which takes variant list of mouse 
     * co-ordinates as argument 
     */ 
    apiPtr->invoke("mousePositionCallback", FB::variant_list_of(evt->m_x)(evt->m_y)); 
  }
}
```

As i get, last string must run `mousePositionCallback` function in my JavaScript with argument of `FB::variant_list`;
But I cant understand purpose of apiPtr pointer, where can I get it and how this pointer to `FB::JSAPIPtr` must actually look in my code.

Comment: fix the first line so the code block looks ok..(add one line space between paragraph and code..

Comment: cool, I just edited my answer..have a look at what I'm suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FB::JSAPIPtr type in FireBreath is just a convenience alias for a boost::shared_ptr (shared auto pointer so you do not have to call delete on the object, nor you have to worry about it vanishing)...

Try to add getRootJSAPI() call, this should return the apiPtr For you.

```
bool MirrarOrnaments::onMouseDown(FB::MouseDownEvent *evt, FB::PluginWindow *) 
{
  if(evt->m_Btn == FB::MouseButtonEvent::MouseButton_Left) 
  {
    /** 
     * apiPtr is the pointer to FB::JSAPIPtr 
     * mousePositionCallback is the JSAPI function which takes variant list of mouse 
     * co-ordinates as argument 
     */ 
    // if you want to access it from the API Part
    // FB::JSAPIPtr apiPtr(boost::make_shared<FBYourPluginAPI>(m_plugin));
    //add the next line:
    FB::JSAPIPtr apiPtr = m_plugin.lock()->getRootJSAPI();
    apiPtr->Invoke("mousePositionCallback", FB::variant_list_of(evt->m_x)(evt->m_y)); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Tested code in the last sample, gives me error that `invoke` is not a member of `FB::JSAPI`

Comment: it's Invoke with uppercase.. fixed the sample.

Comment: I suggest you look at the firebrethe samples and documentation, it explains most of it..http://www.firebreath.org/

Comment: ok, while using `getRootJSAPI()` it just says that it's undefined.
while using `FB::JSAPIPtr apiPtr(boost::make_shared<TestPluginAPI>(m_plugin));` says TestPluginAPI::TestPluginAPI(TestPluginAPI &): cannot convert parameter 1 from "TestPluginWeakPtr" to "TestPluginAPI &"

Comment: ok then try one of the following: either try to use the m_plugin->Invoke or try to apiPtr(boost::make_shared<TestPluginAPI(*m_plugin)) or apiPtr(boost::make_share<TestPluginAPI>(m_plugin->lock())

Comment: sadly none of these works =(
On `...(*m_plugin)` it's `"illegal indirection"`
On `...(*m_plugin)->lock()` it's bunch of errors: `'boost::shared_ptr<X> boost::make_shared(2-9 arg's here)' : expects 2-9 arguments - 1 provided.`
And if i just replase apiPtr with m_plugin it's `type "boost::weak_ptr<T>" does not have an overloaded member "operator ->"`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30355/discussion-between-dory-zidon-and-sinnersmile)